# Convert SQL Server Timestamp to query string

Tags: timestamp, optimistic-concurrency

I have a table in my sql server database called "Orders"  to which i need to give concurrent access(optimistic concurrency).

To achieve that i have a timestamp column called rversion.

Here is a sample of the code for the action to delete an order :

```
public ActionResult CancelOrder(int? ohid,string rowversion)
{
    /*Validation tests.....**/
                try
                {
                    byte[] rvbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(rowversion);
                    dbRepo.deleteSalesOrderHeaderById((int)ohid, rvbytes);
                    dbRepo.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("MyOrders", "Commande");
                }
                catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException concurrencyex)
                {
                    return View("Error", (object)"Concurrency error, the order that you tried to delete was updated or deleted by another user, please retry again");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return View("Error", (object)"Uknown error , please retry");
                }
    
}
```

I have two questions:

Is it practical to pass the rowversion as a parameter in the URL? as i need that to populate the cancel order links in the orders view.

Second, as we see the Timestamp field of the database was converted by entity framework as byte[] ,how to convert it to string to pass to the url , and reconvert it back to the database as timestamp?

As we can see in the code i tried to convert from string to byte[] like this, but i have to be sure it's the right thing

```
byte[] rvbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(rowversion)
```

Thank you.